# How to find information about all sessions for a web-app/site

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to create an admin screen that will give me details about all open sessions in an application/site.  I would also like to know how many session objects are active for each of them

Session object gives me info about my current session. How do i find info about all open sessions. How many sessions are active, etc.

Thanks,

SK

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this in your ASP.Net code, and not by using a web server tool, you can increment a counter in an Application (or Cache) variable on `Session_Start`, and decrement it on `Session_End` in `Global.asax`.

If you want to know more than the count of active users, you can accumulate user information in a collection there -- a `List<T>` of User objects, perhaps.

Here's some code to get you started with this approach:

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Lock();
        Application["SessionCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["SessionCount"]) + 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Lock();
        Application["SessionCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["SessionCount"]) - 1;
        Application.UnLock();
    }
```

Comment: This is more like telling me the total number of concurrent users on my site. Ok...that was the easy part. But I would also like to know how many session objects are active for each of them.

Comment: You might want to edit your question so that it indicates what information you are actually looking for. You aren't mentioning session objects there.